# Biconnected Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

How do you find out whether an undirected graph is [Biconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_graph) or not using its depth first search traversal. 
Is there any other way than traversing the whole graph to find disconnected pieces of the graph.

Answer (score 3):

You calculate the `low(v)` for every vertex in linear time (i.e. during the execution of the DFS). And there exists a bridge (i.e. an edge whose removal will disconnect the graph ==> not biconnected) iff there's a non-root vertex whose `low` value is itself OR if the root has more than one child.

It's explained here on point 5.2 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~lai/780/graph.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I have no answer to this, but my gut feeling would suggest that you would have to do the depth first search traversal as the biconnected property of the graph is a property of the whole graph and not any subset of the graph.

Comment: Or may be we can check for the number of nodes reachable from the the current node before and after removal of an articulated node.

Comment: If the test fails for the current removed node then good => Graph is not biconnected. But need to repeat over all nodes when they pass (or until it fails) => Graph is biconnected

Comment: Agreed (assuming that this is a general graph without any special properties). Proof outline: Let's say that there is an algorithm that doesn't traverse the entire graph - for instance, in a specific graph _G_, it doesn't look at the edge _e1_. Then, the algorithm must necessarily give the same answer for the graph _G'_ that you get by removing _e1_ from _G_ as it did for _G_. However, the removal of _e1_ could have been the only edge that made _G_ biconnected, such that _G'_ is not biconnected. Then, the algorithm produces an incorrect answer for either _G_ or _G'_.

Comment: Yeah DFS is conspicuous but simply applying DFS will of `O(n(n+m))` where `n`=number of vertices and `m`=number of edges